# submitting and calculating

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, field

Html

`

```
 <fieldset id="persoon">
  <legend>mijn gegevens</legend>
 <table>



<tbody><tr>
 <td>
  <label for="bg">Auto gebruik   1 op</label>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input id="bg" name="bg" size="30" type="number" placeholder="Benzine gebruik?">
  </td>
 </tr>

<tr>
  <td>
   <label for="kilometer">kilometer per jaar</label>
   </td>
   <td>
     <input id="kilometer" z="" name="kilometer" size="30" type="number" placeholder="ex: 120000 km/pj">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>
    <label for="benzine">prijs benzine </label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input id="benzine" name="benzine" size="30" type="number">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="bereken"> </td><td>
  </td></tr>
  <tr>
      <td>
    <label for="berekening">Besparing </label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input id="berekening" name="berekening" size="30" type="number">
    </td>
  </tr>
```

`

Javascript/Jquery

```
$('#submit').click(function(evt) {
evt.preventDefault(); // this will prevent the form from being submitted
var bg = parseFloat($('#bg').val());  // parseFloat for floating point
var bf = parseFloat($('#kilometer').val());
var bd = $('bf').val($('bf').val() + $('bf').val() / bg);
var bz = parseFloat($('#benzine').val());
var total = bz * bd ;
total = total.toFixed(2);

});
```

ok so what i'm trying to accomplish is that someone fills in the form:

```
  1: howmany kilometers on 1 liter gas
  2: howmany kilometers you drive a year
  3: howmuch the gas costs
         submit
  4:calculation
```

after someone has entered their stuff, you press "bereken" and it should calculate everything and put it in the "besparing" input field, but it's not working and i can't find anyone to help me personaly.

I am very new to this

Answer (score 0):

Use an input type button rather than input type submit.  Submit is for submitting a form.

And rather than having a .submit use .click in your jquery

EDIT:  Also, the code that retreives the values from the html inputs needs to be in a function otherwise these values in javascript will not be updated.

Pseudo code

```
1. Create function which is call on click using javascript .click function
2. Add in code that retreieves values from fields inside this click function
3. Calculate
4. Output result
```

This should all be done inside the one function.

Comment: i changed it and it doesn't refresh and it doesnt give me error post request anymore either, but i never used .submit, it was .click

Comment: Yes but you were using a submit input type which should only be used in a form.  You do not need any of the blur functionality.  It would be useful to repost your code or a link to pastebin with the new code on it so we can see what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this :

```
$('#submit').click(function(evt) {
   evt.preventDefault(); // this will prevent the form from being submitted
   // your calculations here
});
```

No need to update on `.blur()` you can do it all in the `click` function - that way you dont unnecessarily populate the global namespace with variables

Im not sure you calculations are correct though - you might want to check that `.val()` is returning a number ... have a look at [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) and [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) ie

```
var bg = $('#bg').val();
```

should be

```
var bg = parseFloat($('#bg').val());  // parseFloat for floating point
```

this

```
var bd = $('#bf').val(+$('bf').val() / bg);
```

will not work - you need do something like

```
var bd = $('#bf').val($('#bf').val() + $('bf').val() / bg);
```

I would suggest that you first get all of the values

```
var bd = parseFloat($('#bf').val());
var km = parseFloat($('#kilometer').val());
var bf = parseFloat($('#bf').val());
var bg = parseFloat($('#bg').val());
```

Then use the variables to calculate (for example)

```
var total = bd + km;
```

Comment: This is not correct since he is not using a form.  He should be using input type button and using click binding rather than submit

Comment: Ill take your word for it, I have just always been taught that input type submit for forms, input type button otherwise.  I dont see any reason to use a submit input outside of a form really.

Comment: @JonTaylor i would imagine that there is a `<form>` tag on the page - because there are `input` elements on it - the HTML that the OP has posted is not complete (as its missing the `bf` field for a start) .. I personally would always use anchors `a` for triggering actions when not within a form - they can be styled as buttons .. but thats my personal choice i guess !

Comment: I wouldn't assume anything, theres absolutley no need to use a form in this situation.  I wouldn't say theres any benefit to using anchors instead of buttons outside of forms.  At least I have never come across any problems using either method.  One thing I do know is that even if it works you should never use a submit outside a form, its just bad practise.

Comment: @ManseUK alright. i updated the code so everything is past .click. it still doens't work though. as for the input id's there are only 4.

Comment: @DannyBrouwer what doesnt work ? what does your debugger say ?

Comment: @ManseUK uhm, i use jsfiddle.net, i never used debug.  the entire calculation and showing it